# Questions about cyclic groups (Paar-Pelzl).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to solve this exercise, but it has been long since I studied groups and I am stuck. This is problem 8.3. in Paar-Pelzl 'Understanding Cryptography'. It refers to the previous two problems, so I put them here too:

> **Problem 8.1** Determine the order of all elements of the multiplicative groups of $\mathbb Z ^* _5$, $\mathbb Z ^* _7$ and $\mathbb Z ^* _{13}$.
>
> **Problem 8.2** We consider the group $\mathbb{Z}_{53}^{*}$ (the cyclic group of order $52$). What are the possible element orders? How many elements exist for each order?

This is the problem I want to solve:

> **Problem 8.3.** We now study the groups from Problem 8.2.
>
> 1. How many elements does each of the multiplicative groups have?
> 2. Do all orders from above divide the number of elements in the corresponding multiplicative group?
> 3. Which of the elements from Problem 8.1. are primitive elements?
> 4. Verify for the groups that the number of primitive elements is given by $\phi(\vert\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{*}\vert)$.

This is what I get for Problem 8.3.:

1. I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{53}^{*}$ has order $52$. Its prime decomposition is $$52=13\cdot 2 \cdot 2.$$Then the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{53}^{*}$ have cardinal $26$, $13$, $4$ and $2$. Is this right?
2. Can the order of a cyclic group be different than the number of elements? I thought it was the same thing.
3. We have the primitive elements $2,3\in \mathbb Z^* _5$, $3,5\in \mathbb Z^* _7$ and $2, 6, 7, 11\in \mathbb Z ^* _{13}$. I computed this programming it in the computer and trying all the powers modulo $n$ of each element in each group (and looking for loops). Is there an easier way to know the primitive elements?
4. I've looked in the bibliography and I don't know which function is this. I think maybe it is Euler's totient function, but then what I got in the previous part would be wrong.

Thank you for your help and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Just a comment: $1$ is not a prime number, so a prime decomposition can't contain $1$. For point  2: yes, it's the same. For point $4$, $\phi$ (or $\varphi$) is *Euler's totient function*.

Comment: @Bernard But I found $2$, $2$ and $4$ primitive elements respectively, and I have seen that $\phi(5) =4,  \phi (7) =6, \phi(13)=12$. What is wrong here?

Comment: Nothing is wrong: the number of primitive elements is not the number of elements in the group. It is $\varphi(|G|)$ if $G$ is the (multiplicative) group. Indeed $\varphi(4)=\varphi(6)=2$ and $\varphi(12)=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The subgroups of a *cyclic* group of order $n$ have as orders *all* possible divisors of $n$, and they're all cyclic. Indeed, if $a$ is a generator,  the subgroup  generated by $a^k$ has order
   $$\frac{n}{n\wedge k},\quad\text{where }\;n\wedge k=\gcd(a,k).$$
   Thus, if $d$ is any divisor of $n$, $a^{n/d}$  has order $d$.

Also $a^k$ generates the same the same subgroup as $a^{k'}$ if and only if $\gcd(n,k)=\gcd(n,k')$.

The number of divisors of $52=2^2\cdot 13$ is $(2+1)(1+1)=6$.

3. Once you've found one primitive element $a$, the other  primitive elements can be obtained as powers $a^k$, where $k$ is coprime to the ordre of the multiplicative group.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed a typo in $52=2^2 \cdot 3$. When you say it has 6 subgroups, does it include itself and the trivial one? Because I only get $\mathbb Z _{26}$, $\mathbb Z _{13}$, $\mathbb Z_{4}$ and $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo. Yes, it includes *all* subgroups.